# Can't pass array to HTML data attribute for Bootstrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I'm using version 5.2 of Bootstrap. I'm trying to use the [fallbackPlacements option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/#options) of the Tooltips plugin. The problem is that `fallbackPlacement` takes an array, but doesn't seem to accept one through the data attribute, which the same documentation says should be possible by using the data attribute `bs-data-fallback-placement`:

```
<span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="auto" 
 data-bs-fallback-placements="['top','bottom']" title="This is the tooltip text">Hover Over Me</span>
```

Instead, this causes the tooltip to fail with the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: TOOLTIP: Option "fallbackPlacements" provided type "string" but expected type "array".
```

Is there a way to pass the array through to the data attribute, or is this a bug with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet for what you want to achieve.

I logged the string that is located inside the `bs-data-fallback-placement` to a new array and then reset the `dataset` attribute of your `span` element.

Correct me if I am wrong if that is what you want to achieve.

```js
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

let dataset = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].dataset.bsFallbackPlacements;

let string = dataset.replace("\"", "").replace("\[", "").replace("\]", "").replace(/['"]+/g, '');

let array = string.split(",");

console.log(array);

span.dataset.bsFallbackPlacements = array;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="auto" data-bs-fallback-placements="['top','bottom']" title="This is the tooltip text">Hover Over Me</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll test this solution later to confirm it works, but if it takes a hack like this just to pass an array through to something in the documentation that expects an array, I think this probably counts as a Bootstrap bug. Maybe I'll report it as one later.